# Tagged dispatch with variadic templates, c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-function

I'm trying to make a function accept different arguments depending on the enum.

```
// cake.h
#pragma once
#include <utility>

enum class TYPE { CupCake, Jelly, BirthdayCake };

struct cake_tin { /* etc etc */ };

/** Fills in different ingredients for different types of cake */
template <TYPE, typename ...Args>
void fill_tin(cake_tin &tin, Args... args);

/** Bakes a cake */
template <TYPE type, typename ...Args>
void bake_cake(Args&&...args) {
    cake_tin tin;
    fill_tin<type>(tin, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

.cpp file contains the specialisations of the function

```
// cake.cpp
#include "cake.h"

// If I put this in cake.h, I get multiple definition error (since the template's fully specalised), but if I move this to the .cpp file, I get undefined reference when I compile
template <>
void fill_tin<TYPE::CupCake>(cake_tin &tin, int cherries) {
    // ... etc etc
}

template <>
void fill_tin<TYPE::Jelly>(cake_tin &tin, bool wobble) {
    // ... etc etc
}
```

For completeness

```
// main.cpp
#include "cake.h"

int main() {
    bake_cake<TYPE::CupCake>(1);
}
```

Another file that includes `cake.h`

```
// other.cpp
#include "cake.h"
```

Compile with `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 main.cpp other.cpp -o main`

I've tried putting in declarations

```
template <> void fill_tin<TYPE::CupCake>(cake_tin &tin, int cherries);
template <> void fill_tin<TYPE::Jelly>(cake_tin &tin, bool wobble);
```

and still can't get that template instantiated. If I move the specialisations into the header then they'll cause redefinition when the header is included in multiple compilation units at the link stage.

My question is: How can I get this to work, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The specializations still need the same parameter list. I'm surprised you don't get [a compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e2cb53f2114298).

Comment: Change `template <> void fill_tin<TYPE::CupCake>(cake_tin &tin, int cherries);` to `extern template void fill_tin<TYPE::CupCake>(cake_tin &tin, int cherries);`. Note the `extern`. Same for the `Jelly` specialisation.

Comment: @chris this is a specialisation of a variadic template [though](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f3a9cf603c8d04).

Comment: @Simple I've put them in `cake.h` and am still getting undefined reference at link

Comment: @HerpDerpington I just ran a test in VS2013 and with the extern changes it works. http://pastebin.com/cR1kqfnj

Comment: @HerpDerpington, Hmm, interesting.

Comment: @Simple I don't have VS to test right now, but both clang and g++ are rejecting it.

Comment: FWIW, I tested your current code as is with g++ and it compiles and links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to mix template specialization with function overloading is always going to be horribly painful.

Either provide class template specializations:

```
template<TYPE> struct tin_filler;  // undefined
template<> struct tin_filler<TYPE::CupCake> {
    void operator()(cake_tin& tin, int cherries); };
template<> struct tin_filler<TYPE::Jelly> {
    void operator()(cake_tin& tin, bool wobble); };

template <TYPE type, typename ...Args>
void bake_cake(Args&&...args) {
    cake_tin tin;
    tin_filler<type>()(tin, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Or use `integral_constant` to reify the `TYPE` and use normal function overloading:

```
void fill_tin(std::integral_constant<TYPE, TYPE::CupCake>, cake_tin& tin, int cherries);
void fill_tin(std::integral_constant<TYPE, TYPE::Jelly>, cake_tin& tin, bool wobble);

template <TYPE type, typename ...Args>
void bake_cake(Args&&...args) {
    cake_tin tin;
    fill_tin(std::integral_constant<TYPE, type>(), tin, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The former is more general, but the latter could well be clearer and simpler in this case.